# I want to build the Nodejs core library for share to my employee,

Tags: node.js

I want to build the Nodejs core library for share to my employee, but the code is open and readable. I don't want my developer to know the algorithm inside my library. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extend [@molamk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10867050/molamk)'s answer: there **is** a way to do it without REST API or any kind of server logic. However, not in NodeJS directly.

NodeJS is able to import C/C++ libraries and use their functions. This is known as [Node FFI](https://github.com/node-ffi/node-ffi) (Foreign Function Interface). That means, you can write the code you want to hide as C++ library and deploy it along with the NodeJS code to import it.

Comment: so for c++ library we can compile it to unreadable and import to nodejs project, is that right?

Comment: @EricThakvika Exactly. You can, for instance, compile a lib.so file, which consists of unreadable object code and import it with `node-ffi` into your project.

Answer (score 1):

> the code is open and readable. I don't want my developer to know the algorithm inside my library. Is there any way to do it?

**No**. If you shared the library with someone, there's no way you can prevent them from reading the code inside it. Your algorithm will be known

> Is there any way to do it?

**Yes** but it's not by sharing the complete library. You need to **separate the sensitive part of your code from the rest**. Now you will have 2 parts

1. The API level, which is the *"not sensitive"* part. This is the part that the other person interacts with directly and is *"open to read"*. A good example is the Google Cloud SDK which allows to interact with internal resources in a certain way without exposing the implementation of those services themselves even if you read the SDK's code
2. The *"sensitive"* part. You can do this in many ways that don't involve sharing their implementation. For example you can

   - Put the logic in a server behind a Rest/SOAP API (recommended)
   - Compile your code into a binary and have the API interact with it (if it's really sensitive, you may consider that reverse-engineering the binary a *"valid"* risk here)